# use linphonec on mac

Tags: macos, linphone, linphone-sdk

I've installed the 3.9.1 `.pkg` of Linphone on my mac (Yosemite 10.10.4), but `linphonec` does not seem to be available on the console.

I also installed Linphone on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine from the repos, and `linphonec` was available immediately.

Is there an additional set of steps required to enable `linphonec` on the mac?

Comment: Yeah set your `$PATH`.

Comment: Set `$PATH` to ______?

Comment: The place where you installed the binary.

Comment: the Mac .pkg installer didn't ask me for an install location, and `locate` doesn't turn up a result for `linphonec` or `linphone`.  Is there a way to determine the location of the binary?

Comment: I don't know where it would have installed it.

Comment: @ChrisMeyer, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Use a different OS or a different sip stack.